# MaxPairwiseProduct Java

Tags: java

I wrote method for getting max pairwise product but when I test method with input 100000 and 90000, I can't get a long value. I get result 410065408.

```
static long getMaxPairwiseProduct(int[] numbers) {

      int index1 = 0;

      for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[index1] < numbers[i])
            index1 = i;
    }

      int index2;

      if (index1 == 0){
          index2 = 1;
      }else {
          index2 = 0;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i]!=numbers[index1] && numbers[index2]<numbers[i]){
            index2 = i;
        }
    }
      long res = (long)(numbers[index1] * numbers[index2]);

      return res;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[2];
    numbers[0] = 100000;
    numbers[1] = 90000;
    System.out.println(getMaxPairwiseProduct(numbers));

}
```

Comment: You need to cast before multiplying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In here you are only casting the result

```
long res = (long)(numbers[index1] * numbers[index2]);
```

So it will overflow the integer at time of making the multiply

```
long res = ((long)numbers[index1] * numbers[index2]);
```

Comment: You only need to cast one side.